# In Google Play will limits the apps to read SMS from Year 2019, if the App is not a Default SMS App?

Tags: android, google-play-services, telephonymanager

Currently am Working on to read user SMS from `Telephony.Sms.Inbox`, fetch offer related SMS and Categories it, then showing to user in Proper way to utilize the offers.

Recently Google announced they have made some changes in Google Play to **Protecting User**. In blogs they said in future full access of reading user SMS by only the App as Default SMS App. Even user **Allow the permission to read SMS** .

To **Providing a safe and secure experience for our users** we made these changes.

**My Question is**

1. Any other way to took OTP from SMS which is received by user?
2. If my App wants to read SMS means, my App should be a default SMS App. No other way to read SMS
3. Whats is the Exact date of this feature Roll out in Google Play.

**Update**

[Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9mjhvc/google_play_restricts_the_use_of_the_sms_and_call/)

Comment: can you please provide official thread?

Comment: @PrakashBala see https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any other way to took OTP from SMS which is received by user?

You need to use SMS Retriever API, you can perform SMS-based user verification in your app automatically, without requiring the user to manually type verification codes, and without requiring any extra app permissions.

More info on API can be found over https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

> If my App wants to read SMS means, my App should be a default SMS App. No other way to read SMS

Google Play may provide a temporary exception to apps that aren't Default SMS, Phone, or Assistant handlers when:

- Use of the permission provides core app functionality to users
- There is currently no alternative method to provide the core functionality

you must fill this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfbmF-9G249UDLJZpEvJpjgwP8rjvvLyWyNYnFPrsqYjMNckg/viewform) and google must approve it

> Whats is the Exact date of this feature Roll out in Google Play.

Right now I am not sure I will try to find more info

**Edit**

You must submit form by January 9, 2019

> Apps that fail to meet policy requirements or submit a Permissions Declaration Form by January 9, 2019 may be removed from Google Play.

more info can be found over [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303) ,[Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9mjhvc/google_play_restricts_the_use_of_the_sms_and_call/)

Comment: question to who filled the exception form - how quick did they answer and approve it?

Comment: What happens to non-GooglePlay apps which are released from private store? will they impacted due to this?

Comment: @SantoshSalunke AFAIK they won't be impacted any way as long as google play protect won't mess up with them