# How to handle a rejection based on new Android Store policies regarding permissions?

Tags: android, google-play

While I am updating an app on Play store. I am getting following error according to the new policy of Google:

I have also checked all the options that are available, but again and again, Google rejects my application.

I am new to Android.

> Issue: Violation of Permissions policy
>
> After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the following reason(s):
>
> Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality {SMS-based financial transactions (e.g., 5 digit messages), and related activity including OTP account verification for financial transactions and fraud detection}. Please remove these permissions from your app.

This is my manifest containing permissions I have declared

[image: This is my manifest containing permissions I have declared]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954921/why-i-getting-sms-and-call-log-permissions-warning/53955029#53955029 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53006891/6478047

Comment: Your question is at risk of downvotes or closure [because of this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please repair it (by posting text and not images) as soon as you can.

Answer (score 1):

SMS permission is no more allowed to read OTP as android is going to give this feature to users out of the box.
You have to register as a messaging app to get SMS and CALL_LOG permissions.

Comment: I have got redistered and also get approved but it is is not accepting my update. It is showing that you need to click your Core functionality.

Comment: And when I select my core functionalaity. The updtae got rejected, So I want to remove my those permission in my new update How can i do that

Comment: Search for SMS and CALL_LOG throughout your project to confirm your code is not asking for permissions. Also please make sure none of your libraries are asking for permissions.

Comment: i have go through the all code but  my application donot need the SMS and LOG function But google is asking me for the core funcationality, And I have selected the functionality but Google rejects me

Comment: You should not select core functionality as messaging if your app is not a messaging app. Please go through your libraries and check if any of the libraries are asking for SMS permissions.

Answer (score 0):

So recently, Google changed its policies, read it at [XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-restriction-sms-call-log-permissions/)

Same thing happened with my app, It got removed from play store, for using SMS features.

You need to remove those permissions from Android Manifest and if you need to send a message to someone, you need to use Intents to form a message and fill out the messaging app and user has to manually send the message.

Or if you are trying to access SMS permission for automatic OTP, there are other ways to do it.

As it turns out, you need to fill a form. Read this article from [Google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102) and refer to this answer on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53921068/4204668)

Comment: I have removed the Permission from  the manifiest buit again it is not accepting my update

Comment: I am assuming you also fixed the code and are not trying to access SMS or CALL_LOGS in any position possible, am I right?

Comment: Yes I am not in need for accepting the SMS and CALL_LOGS How can I change the  permission for the new updtae any Suggestion! Please

Comment: have you any code for that which i can implement in android app

Comment: i have read your answer that is send to me the XDA developers

Comment: Did you read this :- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102
Basically, after you edit the code, and submit the upgraded version, you need to Complete the Permissions Declaration Form. It is very very important, and if you follow this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102 
It has all the steps on how to do it

Comment: yes i have read it and read the Decleration form and also google accept my request but it is now asking for core functionality.

Comment: Is the an option through which i can again remove my permission from the manifest

Comment: I have also add manifiest photograph inside my Post You can check there

Comment: Ok, found something on Stackoverflow, see if this helps 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54694479/4204668

Let me know when you are done with A1 to B3
Don't do C part as you don't have any SMS or CALL_LOG permission in your manifest anymore

Comment: Thanks But there is no any option coming for the permission declation form inside the Artifact library Option

Comment: @walkmoney did you found out any solution.I am also facing the same

Comment: Hey @MujammilAhamed, I was also facing the same issue, What I did was just submitted a new app, with fixing the code and removing the bad permissions. It got accepted automatically.

Comment: @Pulkit, I have the smallest real-time users using the app. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Do not update your minSdkVersion in this release. You need to rollout removal of permissions for all of your users.

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating previous versions of your apk on play console. If you updated minSdkVersion of your app and did not deactivate older apks, older devices are still served the apk with permissions.

This worked for me!